# PHPMailer with Migadu not working

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using Migadu mail server and PHP Mailer to set up a simple contact form.

This is the PHP file:

```
<?php

    require("includes/class.phpmailer.php");
    require("includes/class.smtp.php");

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $smtpHost = "smtp.migadu.com";
    $smtpUsername = "info@mywebsite.com";
    $smtpPassword = "mypassword";

    $to = 'info@mywebsite.com';

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->CharSet = "utf-8";

    $mail->Host = $smtpHost;
    $mail->Username = $smtpUsername;
    $mail->Password = $smtpPassword;

    $mail->From = $smtpUsername;
    $mail->FromName = $name;
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($email);

    $mail->Subject = "Contact Form";

    $body = '<h1>Contact!</h1>';
    $body .= '<p><b>Name: </b>'.$name.'</p>';
    $body .= '<p><b>Email: </b>'.$email.'</p>';
    $body .= '<p><b>Message: </b>'.$message.'</p>';

    $mail->Body = $body;

    $sentStatus = $mail->Send();

    if($sentStatus){
        echo json_encode(['status' => 'ok']);
    }else{
        echo json_encode(['status' => 'error', 'errorType' => 'server']);
    }
?>
```

But it's not sending the mail. Also, it's not throwing any error, it just stuck in loading forever.

Answer (score 0):

It's not showing any error because you're not displaying any errors - look in the `ErrorInfo` property. *All* of the examples provided with PHPMailer do this, so [go look at them](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples) to see how to do that.

It's most likely that it's not "stuck forever", it's just that the timeout is long, and that's probably because your ISP blocks outbound SMTP, which is very common. [The troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) tells you how to diagnose this. Your ISP probably has an alternative method for sending email, for example they may provide their own relay, so you should refer to their docs.

Comment: Actually, the problem was DigitalOcean block SMTP for the first 60 days, I tried the `telnet` command from the troubleshooting guide and it didn't respond so I opened a ticket and they told me that.